# Pip resolution with extra-index

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, aws-codeartifact

I am trying to set up a build pipeline with two python package repositories.
I'd like pip to first search in the public PyPi repos, and only if it cannot find a package or a version there, it should look it up in another private repo (AWS CodeArtifact).

My pip config is

```
global.index-url='https://pypi.org/simple'
global.extra-index-url='***.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/public/simple/'
```

Note that this codeartifact repo has **PyPi as upstream**, i.e. I can fetch all dependencies through this repo alone.

The output looks like this

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, ***.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/public/simple/
[...]
Collecting blinker==1.4
  Downloading https://***.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/public/simple/blinker/1.4/blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
Collecting boto3==1.16.40
  Downloading https://***.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/public/simple/boto3/1.16.40/boto3-1.16.40-py2.py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Collecting callee==0.3.1
  Downloading https://***.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/public/simple/callee/0.3.1/callee-0.3.1.tar.gz (19 kB)
[...]
```

You can see that even though codeartifact is only the extra-index, each dependency is downloaded from it.

When I **remove the upstream**, i.e. only a few private packages reside in the codeartifact repo, then PyPi is checked first.

```
[...]
Collecting blinker==1.4
  Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
Collecting boto3==1.16.40
  Downloading boto3-1.16.40-py2.py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Collecting callee==0.3.1
  Downloading callee-0.3.1.tar.gz (19 kB)
[...]
```

Can you help me understanding this behaviour?